# how to replace TreeView's selected node with newly created node

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a populated treeView with Node I created, there are several node classes, all inherit from treeNode.

When i edit a node (using a GUI dialog), it may change to different class, so I'm creating a new node in that process, and trying to replace the selected node with my new node, but that doesn't work, the node stays the old one, cant figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Code:

```
TreeNodeMission mission = (TreeNodeMission)treeView.SelectedNode;
TreeNodeMission newMission = ChangeMissionDialog(mission);

treeView.SelectedNode = newMission; // doesn't work
```

Also tried removing and adding it, also doesn't work

```
index = treeView.Nodes.IndexOf(treeView.SelectedNode);  // index returns -1
treeView.Nodes.Remove(treeView.SelectedNode);
treeView.Nodes.Insert(index, newMission);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Update:
treeView.SelectedNode is not null, its a valid node i selected.

Comment: You sure SelectedNode isn't null?

Comment: If `index` returns `-1`, it is an indication that there is no node selected, therefore any code pertaining to it will not work.

Comment: What kind of application is it? WPF or Winforms  or something else?
If it is WPF is your SelectedNode notifying?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk: As the question is tagged in `winforms` I strongly guess that it is not a WPF TreeView ;)

Comment: @Aschratt it is retagged :) before it wasn't winforms

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, found the bug.

I found a way to replace the node, by removing and re-adding it.
I guess i thought asking for index will give me general index in the tree, but it gives index to the parent only, so using the parent node, i can replace it:

```
int index = treeView.SelectedNode.Index;
treeView.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.RemoveAt(index);
treeView.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Insert(index, mission);
treeView.SelectedNode = mission;
```

Thanks