# C# How to replace selected node text without removing the child node on treeview?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, .net-4.6

[image]

I have a treeview node with 3 layer of hierarchy. Currently, the function for Add, Remove working. They only left is append the modified text into the selected node without remove the node before insert?

I have seen some of the question on this forum and from search engine result but the solutions look not like what I need.

Solutions that I found:-

1. Get the selected node index, remove it, insert new to selected index node. On [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14955039/3436326)
2. Loop inside treeview node, to find and replace selected node string with new string. On [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336802/3436326).

Why I can't follow above idea?

1. If the selected node were remove first, so does the child will remove too?
2. If there is more than 1 node that have same text, it must be replace on recursive loop.

What I have now are the index of Parent and Current Selected. So, it will be two index of hierarchy.

```
indxparent.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Index.ToString() ?? "-";
indxchild.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Index.ToString() ?? "-";
```

How to programming of amend new text to the selected node/ to the selected node index?

Working code use before Kempeth proposed his solutions:
Method 1:

```
string newdata = "This is new information data";
TreeView1.LabelEdit = true;
if (!TreeView1.SelectedNode.IsEditing)
{
    TreeView1.SelectedNode.BeginEdit();
    TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text = newdata;
    TreeView1.SelectedNode.EndEdit(false);
}
```

Method 2:

```
string newdata = "This is new information data";
TreeNode node = new TreeNode(newdata);
TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.RemoveAt(IndexOfSelectedNode);
TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Insert(IndexOfSelectedNode, node);
TreeView1.SelectedNode = node;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried simply setting the `Text` property of the `SelectedNode`?

```
TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text + " MAGIC!"
```

Comment: Seriously man. I have try some like this. Not exactly like this but likely and failed. So, I've been stress finding the answer before I posted here for halfday of my workday.

I even search using BeginEdit just not to remove which as I need.  

    string newdata = "The new information data";
    Treeview1.LabelEdit = true;
    if (!Treeview1.SelectedNode.IsEditing)
    {
        Treeview1.SelectedNode.BeginEdit();
        Treeview1.SelectedNode.Text = newdata;
        Treeview1.SelectedNode.EndEdit(false);
    }  

But your solution, direct hit.. Thanks @Kempeth